# Why aren't Guava ImmutableCollections interfaces?

Tags: java, guava, immutability

Guava's `ImmutableCollection` has sub-classes like `ImmutableList` that are (non-extendable) abstract classes rather than interfaces. The [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) says this is to prevent external subtyping. On the other hand, the documentation also says they

> should be thought of as interfaces in every important sense

But isn't the ability to externally subtype an important sense of an interface? For instance, if `ImmutableList` was an interface, I could have a method signature like

```java
public ImmutableList<String> getNames();
```

(as is the Guava recommendation), and then have the flexibility to swap in a custom implementation of `ImmutableList` in the future. However, since in reality it is an abstract class, I don't have this flexibility, and therefore am bound to Guava's implementations. Thus, if I want to maintain this flexibility, I'd have to revert to using the more general return type of `List`, which no longer conveys the helpful information about immutability to callers:

```java
public List<String> getNames();
```

So why is it important that these not be externally sub-typed? One answer might be that the Guava designers don't trust external implementors to properly support the required semantics, but `List` itself actually has pretty extensive contract, and no one is preventing custom implementations of that. Or are there other reasons?

Comment: "*But isn't the ability to externally subtype an important sense of an interface?*" - This sounds like an argument towards the developer than something we could answer without biasness; this question will only generate opinipn-based answers unless the actual developer answers. The actual answer to the titled question is in the question itself. May want switch to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) to question the design choice, unless you're asking for a workaround. I personally think this is a good question, just not proper for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Google is less trusting than Oracle :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because there's no way to have the type `ImmutableList` guarantee immutability if it's an interface.

And no, I don't think the ability for anyone to write their own implementation of an `interface` is a necessary property of all interfaces. Consider, for example, sealed types, which only allow a specific set of implementations that are defined in the same file. They can still be `interface`s (there's a proposal that includes `sealed interface` for Java [here](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html)) without allowing anyone in the world to create an implementation of them.

I'd also be really curious as to why you'd think you might want your own custom implementation of something super-simple like an immutable list.

Comment: Fair point about the sealed interfaces. As far as your first point though, there is no way to guarantee that custom `Comparator`s implement `compare()` correctly, or that `List` for that matter implements `set()` correctly. .NET is fine with it being an interface. As far as why we'd want our own implementation, it's more of a decorator, but, in a broader sense, if you'd agree it's ok for us to have our own implementation of `List`, then it doesn't seem farfetched we'd want our own `ImmutableList`.